# Dart — onclick action add/remove class

Tags: dart

Now I'm learn Dartlang and don't understand how on this language write onClick action for some cases. I know, it's like a java, but i confused. 
Example: simple case. I have element with class "button" and div element with "dropdown" class. How to add/remove "open" class to "dropdown" element after click element with "button" class?

```
void dropdown(part) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for

```
querySelector('.button').onClick.listen((event) => dropdown(...));
```

Comment: like a `querySelector('button').onClick.listen((event) {
      if (event.target.classes == 'dropdown') {
        event.target.classes.add('open');
      } else {
        event.target.classes.remove('open');
      }
    });`

Comment: I think you might need to use `if (!event.target.classes.contains('dropdown'))`. But the whole thing can be simpler with `toggle()`. Just use `listen((e) => e.target.classes.toggle('dropdown'))`